# cannot find webspace with name thff-rg-SouthCentralUSwebspace

Tags: node.js, git, azure, sails.js

I am following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-nodejs-sails-cli-nodejs

When I come to this part:

`azure site create --git <appname>`

I get the error

> error:   Cannot find WebSpace with name
>   thff-rg-SouthCentralUSwebspace.
>   error:   Error information has been recorded to
>   C:\Users\Logan.azure\azure.err
>   error:   site create command failed

I used to be able to get past this point.

> Make sure you're still in the root directory of your Sails.js
>   project. Create the App Service app resource in Azure with a unique
>   app name with the next command. Your web app's URL is
>   http://.azurewebsites.net.

Am i supposed to make an app service through azure portal and then type this command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: Cannot find WebSpace with name thff-rg-SouthCentralUSwebspace.
>   error: Error information has been recorded to
>   C:\Users\Logan.azure\azure.err 
> error: site create command failed

I was also running into this problem with [azure cli](https://github.com/azure/azure-xplat-cli) v0.10.6 today. 
This is how I solved the problem, go into the .azure directory (`C:\Users\{youraccountname}\.azure`) and find the `spaces.{someGuid}` JSON file, and just delete this file. Then, re-run your command.

For more options, see [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues/1646) on GitHub.

For make an app server through [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com), you can refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac).